# batch save process, post_save not running?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm running a batch save process, however my post_save function does not seem to be running for each object? Can anyone stop any issues?

save function

```
 objs = [
        Message(
            recipient_number=e.mobile,
            content=content,
            sender=e.contact_owner,
            billee=user,
            sender_name=sender,
            gateway=gateway,
        )
        for e in query

    ]
    # Send messages to DB
    Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def my_post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Post Save Signal.
    Sent at the end of the save() method. Attached to 'Message'.
    """
    print("=========================================")
    print(instance.gateway)
    instance.send(instance.gateway)

post_save.connect(my_post_save_handler, sender=Message)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_save` is not fired for, amongst others, `bulk_create` and `update`.

Comment: You could fire it manually, but that would require instatiating the models anyway so you would be better off with regular `for ...` loop with `.save()`, or `bulk_create` then fetch all and fire `.save()` without changing anything.